# Automatic Weight Painting Problem

Tags: weight-painting

When I apply Automatic Wieght Paint Mesh deforms unnaturally as seen on second picture. On the first one is normal mesh without weight paint.[image]
[image]

[image]

I deleted some parts of mesh since this is project work so it can't be used by other. Hope you can work out with this, because problem is on the spine. Let me know if you can't.

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? delete the parts that you don't want to share. https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable each bone constraint visibility, you'll find that you need to switch the *Copy Transforms* constraint of the bone called *Spine.003* from *World Space* to *Local Space*:

[image]

Comment: I see now. Probably changing not only Spine.003 but Spine.004 and so on would be useful too, or it doesn't matter? Thanks, that will solve it.

Comment: yes of course also check the other bones